# Selenium Webdriver not working with ng-click='logout()' (used at least 6 different xPaths)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy

I have the following code:

```
<span class="login-link control" ng-switch="loggedIn()">        
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <a class="site-control ng-binding ng-scope" ng-switch-when="true" ng-click="logout()" href="javascript:void(0)">Logout</a>
        <!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->
```

and used the following xPath's and Css selectors that I've tried out in the Developer console and each time it highlights the code but when I run the code it just sits there but doesn't click on the link

Tried:

```
    //*[contains(@class, 'site-control ng-binding ng-scope') and contains(text(),'Logout')]

    //a[@class='site-control ng-binding ng-scope']

    //a[.='Logout']

    //a[contains(text(),'Logout')]

    //div[@id='menu']/div/ul/li[11]/pwp-site-controls/div/span/a

    //a[contains(@href, 'javascript:void(0)')]

    css - [ng-click='logout()']
```

My current code that does get me to the correct page is:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'site-control ng-binding ng-scope')
```

IntelliJ current error:

```
   [![org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*\[contains(@class, 'site-control ng-binding ng-scope') and contains(text(),'Logout')\] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)][1]][1]
```

Comment: Hi could you change the expected condition from clickable to element  present instead and see of you are actually getting the element or not ?

Comment: If that works fine., could you try getting the value of isdisplayed and isenabled , see if both are returning true or not . For isclicable to work both should return true .

Comment: Try clicking span instead of a

Comment: Thank you!  I will try that right now. I haven't had a chance to work on it yet.

Comment: I ran this: 

if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='site-control ng-binding ng-scope']")).size() != 0){
            System.out.print("Element is Present")
        }else{
            System.out.print("Element is Absent")
        }

and it said that the "Element is Absent"

Comment: I changed it the a to span for the following xpath:

    //a[@class='site-control ng-binding ng-scope']

Comment: hi use explicit wait , presenceofelementlocated. https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

Comment: Dang I tried that and changing the xpath again but still get the following error:

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //span[@class='login-link control']//child::a (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)